How do I create a data frame that is a count based on two variables?
My data would look like this:



Gender
Age range




M
0-10


F
10-20


M
0-10


F
10-20



I want to produce a summary table that would look like this:



Gender
0-10
10-20




M
2
0


F
0
2



Really struggling to find any count or group_by code that does this?
I can't find a way to make the age ranges appear as the columns for the counts.
